# Use dbus to get name of mediaplayer currently playing

Tags: linux, d-bus, mediaplayer

**EDIT: I removed and rewrote most of the post to make the question more direct and to make the post a lot shorter. You can of course view the edit history to get the previous version.**

Using bspwm on Arch Linux. `playerctl` to control media, `sxhkd` to bind media keys to playerctl commands.

I'm trying to find a way to get the latest active media player so when I use the media keys to play/pause a song/movie/.. , my pc automatically controls the latest active mediaplayer.

For instance, when Spotify happens to be open in the background and I'm watching something on VLC, it knows to control VLC and not Spotify when I press media keys. Right now, if both are open, VLC always gets priority from playerctl.

What I need is a way to ask dbus which mediaplayer is currently playing a song, so I can keep it in a file.

---

EDIT: I found a way to ask each spotify and vlc using:

`qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlaybackStatus`

and

`qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlaybackStatus`

but I'd like to automatically ask **all** mediaplayers, not each one by name. I tried to do it with `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.*` but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it this way:

This is a script that always runs to check which player is currently active/was last active, and stores that player in a file:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true ; do
    for m in `qdbus | egrep -i 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2|plasma-browser-integration'` ; do
        if [[ `qdbus $m /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlaybackStatus` == 'Playing' ]]; then
            echo $m > ~/.config/activePlayer/currentPlaying.txt
        fi
    done
    sleep 1
done
```

and this is a script that sends dbus commands like play/pause/etc/ to the player that is currently active (based on that file).   The script gets called by sxhkd which listens to my keypresses.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Get command
case $1 in
    'play-pause')
        cmd='/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause';;
    'next')
        cmd='/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next';;
    'previous')
        cmd='/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous';;
    'stop')
        cmd='/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Stop';;
    'skipForward')
        cmd='/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Seek 5000000';;
    'skipBackward')
        cmd='/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Seek -5000000';;
    *)
esac

#Send command to qdbus
if [[ `qdbus | egrep -i 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2|plasma-browser-integration' | wc -l` -eq 1 ]]; then
    qdbus `qdbus | egrep -i 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2|plasma-browser-integration'` $cmd
else
    qdbus `cat ~/.config/activePlayer/currentPlaying.txt` $cmd
fi

unset cmd
```

Comment: Is your setup using `pulseaudio` ? If so `pacmd list-sink-inputs` will print (among other stuff) something like `application.process.binary = "totem"` ... there's your currently playing app name...

Comment: For me it displays the currently opened apps (it shows spotify and firefox, while both are not playing anything), not the one playing.

Comment: Well, you should only look for the ones with `state: RUNNING`...

Comment: I see. But what would the difference be with what I'm doing now? It works perfectly so far...

Answer (score 2):

In the latest release, you can use [playerctld](https://github.com/altdesktop/playerctl#selecting-the-most-recent-player).

```
playerctl -p playerctld play-pause
```

This will start a persistent process that monitors player activity and gives the command to the active player.